# How to limit each front-end user to view just his own uploaded files on Amazon S3?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, ajax, javascript

In my Wordpress website Users can upload video files directly to a Amazon S3 bucket, all of them use the SAME bucket for their uploads. After the upload is done each user should be able to view/delete just his own files (objects) in the bucket and not the other users files from the front-end of the website. 
What is the best practice to do so? if I need to develop a plugin please give me a clue from where to start ?

Comment: Probably writing plugin is the only option. How you manage uploads? If you want to upload files from user directly to S3 (bypassing application server) you probably need to use [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/). Process can looks like this: User upload file and you save in the app database some metadata about file name, location, which user is owner etc. Then you can check current user and show him only his resources. For deleting files you can use either JS SDK or PHP SDK. In fact it's to broad to fit Q&A format imo...

Comment: @MateuszMarchel Thanks alot. at least i have some clues now :)